# Secure Cookies on http requests

Tags: cookies, https, http-headers, insecure-connection

What happens to secure cookies on http requests. will it be lost over the request? What will happen if the cookie is a secure auth cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-1) formalizes the behavior of HTTP cookies (as they work in the real world, not as they should ideally work, unlike some previous failed RFC):

> 1. Introduction
>
> This document defines the HTTP Cookie and Set-Cookie header fields.

The description of the [behavior of the "secure" flag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.5) follows:

> 4.1.2.5.  The Secure Attribute
>
> The Secure attribute limits the scope of the cookie to "secure"
> channels (where "secure" is defined by the user agent).  When a
> cookie has the Secure attribute, **the user agent will include the
>
> cookie in an HTTP request only if the request is transmitted over a
>
> secure channel** (typically HTTP over Transport Layer Security (TLS)
> [RFC2818]).

**In practice only connections over TLS (that is, HTTP/S) are considered secure.** Browsers could conceivably define direct HTTP connections to host "localhost" or an IP address that is by definition "local" (address of that IP stack), like 127.0.0.1 or ::1, or other local addresses, as secure. That would be in the spirit of the specification. (I don't know browsers that actually do so.)